# jcombobox as cell editor java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, illegalstateexception

I am using a custom JComboBox as a cell editor in a JTable.  When the users gets to the cell using keyboard controls it tries to open the popup.  This causes the following error:

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:1964)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:1938)
    at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.show(JPopupMenu.java:887)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.show(BasicComboPopup.java:191)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.setPopupVisible(BasicComboBoxUI.java:859)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setPopupVisible(JComboBox.java:796)
```

I have seen some articles stating that this is a known problem and the solution is to set:

```
    comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

This however does not help.  What is this supposed to do anyways?

All the threads and articles I have read about this are very vague about the nature of the problem.

Does anyone have any insight into the nature of why this problem occurs?  My combobox is very custom so it would help to understand the basis of the problem so I can fix the code.

This is triggered on a focus gained event on the combo box which is captured and call      setPopupVisible(true);

```
 public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent e)
 {
        //if focus is gained then make sure we show the popup if it is suppose to be visible
            setPopupVisible(true);
        //and highlight the selected text if any
        comboTextEditor.setCaretPosition(comboTextEditor.getText().length());
        comboTextEditor.moveCaretPosition(0);
 }
```

By the way I get the same results in Java 1.7_40 as Java 1.6_45

Full Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:1964)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:1938)
    at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.show(JPopupMenu.java:887)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.show(BasicComboPopup.java:191)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.setPopupVisible(BasicComboBoxUI.java:859)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setPopupVisible(JComboBox.java:796)
    at com.mbs.generic.view.swing.combobox.AutoCompleteComboBox$1.focusGained(AutoCompleteComboBox.java:185)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusGained(AWTEventMulticaster.java:203)
    at java.awt.Component.processFocusEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6046)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4653)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1848)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:901)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:513)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4525)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:648)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:621)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:619)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:618)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

thanks

Comment: I would post a SSCCE if I could make a short one to reproduce but everything involved is custom.  Nevertheless, this problem seems rampant with no clear explanation as why or solution.

Comment: Are trying to open the combo boxes' popup menu yourself?

Comment: Yes on focus gained I call:      setPopupVisible(true);

Comment: `but everything involved is custom.` - then guess where the problem is? Why are you customizing the code? What is your requirement? If we know the requirement, maybe we can make a suggestion.

Comment: I have a custom autocomplete combobox that extends jcombobox.  It works perfectly well in every situation other than when used in a cell editor of a jtable.  It even works fine in a jtable when accessed via a mouse rather than key entry.

Comment: You should try to write a SSCCE to check whether it's a problem of Swing or your code.

Comment: no code - no help possible, it's as simple as this ... Too many thingies could go wrong (been there, see SwingX autocomplete support ;-), wild guesses would be a waste of time.

Comment: @kleopatra I agree an SSCCE would be good. But I've seen this stack trace before doing a very similar thing.  I'm almost positive it's an event ordering problem that can be fixed by calling `setPopupVisible` after the editor is fully initialized. This can be done with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: @Gene - could be (and probably can be worked around with an invokelater, agreed on that :-) though without further info it's a bit too much guessing: the probability of the OP doing something wrong is not zero ...

Answer (score 5):

First, let me explain what `comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);` does. Normally, hoovering the mouse over an item or pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard will cause the selection of items on the `JComboBox` immediately. Since selection events from the `JComboBox` will cause the cell edit process to stop, this behavior is not suitable for table cells. So when setting this special client property items will be shown selected inside the popup list but not set on the `JComboBox` yet. Only committed items (via click or Enter key) will change the selected item on the `JComboBox` causing the end of the edit then. At least, this holds for `BasicLookAndFeel` and its derivatives.

The problem you have is completely different. As the exception message and the stack trace clearly say, the look and feel tries to open the `JPopupMenu` associated with the `JComboBox` (as you requested) but it can’t determine the on-screen location for the popup menu because your `JComboBox` is not shot showing on the screen. The reason why it wants the location of the `JComboBox` is that it opens the new window relative to the `JComboBox`.

The remaining question is why you received a `focusGained` from a `JComboBox` that is not showing on the screen (or why you thought you did).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't see a solution here.  The focus gained occurs when the cell editor gains entry from the keyboard.  I think it transfers focus before it is fully changed from the renderer to editor in the table.  Maybe some timing issue with swing and it isn't technically shown when it occurs.

Comment: @springcorn: but I don’t understand why you are playing around with focus events at all. The Swing table will ask you whether to start cell editing at the right time anyway. Just override `isCellEditable(EventObject)` in your cell editor…

Comment: The CellEditor simple wraps my AutoCompleteComboBox.  The normal behavior of the AutoCompleteComboBox is to open it's popup when it gains focus in order to present the user with choices.  In all other gui non table circumstances this works fine.  So when focus is gained it does so.  From my experience, isCellEditable is called for all kinds of reasons and if I try to open the popup whenever it is called then it will often not be visible when called.  IMO the real question goes back to how is it possible that a focus gained event occurs when the the component is not visible.

Comment: @springcorn: maybe a *complete* stack trace would help…

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: @springcorn: add it to your question, not to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Popups like the pulldown in a JComboBox tend to have edge cases for event handling order because they are not geometrically nested inside their ancestors in the component hierarchy.  In your case, you are causing the box's focus handler to show the pulldown.  To do this it needs the box to be already located on the screen, but it's not.

The solution is almost certainly to defer showing the pulldown until all the events that will make the box visible have been processed.  I had a similar (though not exactly the same) problem and was able to resolve it in this manner.  Happily there is a Swing utility function that does the trick. Try wrapping the body of the focus gained handler in `invokeLater` and a `Runnable`:

```
void focusGained() {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
    ... focus gained body including show of pulldown menu here ... 
  });
}
```

The `invokeLater` puts a new message containing the `Runnable`at the end of the queue, i.e.  *after all the existing ones*.  That `Runnable` is executed only when the message makes it to the head, after all those other messages have been processed.  This is exactly what you want.

Comment: I actually already tried this to no avail.  Thanks for the thought.  It does seem like a very small timing issue

Comment: @springcom Okay. That being the case, you won't be able to get more help until you provide a SSCCE that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks anyways.  Unfortunately, putting together a simple test case to replicate this problem is not possible as the entire gui is very customized.  SSCCE don't always work in these cases.

Comment: @springcorn Can't you just cook up a simple default table that uses a JComboBox as an editor with `focusGained()` showing the popup?  This should be a hundred lines at most, no?  Won't it produce the bug?

Comment: @springcorn I wonder what would happen if you nested 2 `invokeLater`s so that the first calls the second to further delay showing the popup.  Really kludgey, but I'm curious if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I second (third? fourth?) everyone asking for a pared-down example of a table using your custom combobox any maybe a bit of the code from the combobox itself, but just to take a stab at it anyway...have you tried making a customized version of [EditorDelegate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate.html) to go with your other custom code and moving the code for showing the popup from `focusGained()` into your delegate's `startCellEditing()` method?

Answer (score -2):

If you embed your instruction inside a try .. catch instruction , your program will run without problems:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                        public void run()
                        {
                        try {
                        tInput.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
                        tInput.showPopup();
                        }
                        catch   (IllegalComponentStateException e) {
                                return;
                                }

                          }
                 });
```

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to ignore exceptions.  Doubly so if you don't understand where they are coming from and what they mean.