# JComboBox gives IllegalComponentStateException and I don't understand why

Tags: java, exception, user-interface, jcombobox

I am writing a GUI for a simple program that mimics a block of RAM and I wanted to use a JComboBox to let the user select a command option from a drop down list. However, whenever I try to select an option from the list, it gives me an IllegalComponentStateException and says that the component must be showing on the screen to determine its location. Here is the code for creating the main screen.

```
  public static void createMainMenu(){
    mainFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();

    mainFrame.setSize(700 , 500);
    mainFrame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3 , 3));

    JPanel ramStatus = new JPanel();
    ramStatus.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    ramStatus.setSize(200 , 200);

    JLabel heading = new JLabel("Please Select An Option to Continue.");

    JComboBox<String> userChoice = new JComboBox<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++)
        userChoice.addItem(choices[i]);

    userChoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)e.getSource();

        choice = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }});

    JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        handleSelection(choice);
    }});

    mainFrame.add(new JPanel());
    mainFrame.add(userChoice);
    mainFrame.add(enter);

    mainFrame.add(new JPanel());
    mainFrame.add(heading);
    mainFrame.add(new JPanel());

    mainFrame.add(new JPanel());
    mainFrame.add(ramStatus);
    mainFrame.add(new JPanel());

    //Set the frame visible.
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I should mote that choice is a static String variable declared after class declaration. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

********************EDIT***********************************************************************

Here is the error message generated when I select a new option from the drop down menu. The exception is thrown before I hit enter, so it has nothing to do with outside methods.

```
 java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine       
 its location
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2044)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2018)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:390)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:388)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$CallableWrapper.run(LWCToolkit.java:532)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:241)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$CPeerEvent.dispatch(LWCToolkit.java:689)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Give complete information.  Boil your problem down to a minimum runnable program and post ALL of it.  You have an error message, post ALL of it.  Since you do not understand what is going wrong, don't assume you know where the problem is.  I think it's in handleSelection, which, of course, you don't show us.

Comment: @rcook handleSelection is only called when the enter button is pressed, which is not when the error occurs.

Comment: @Gleb Try setting an initial selection with 'userChoice.setSelectedIndex(0);'

Comment: @rcook I posted the error message generated. The problem is not in any outside methods or variables, it occurs immediately after I select an option, before I hit the enter button.

Comment: @stark - the error still occurs when I add that code in. I posted the complete error message (doubt you need all of it), but in any event that is what I'm getting, with and without adding setSelectedIndex(0);

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `addActionListener` to listen to ComboBox item selection? Have you tried using `addItemListener`instead?

Comment: What is the pro of using addItemListener?

Comment: ActionListener will be triggered anytime an item is selected, whether this item was already selected or not (which may cause trouble in your code during the initial item selection)

Comment: Looking at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968815/jcombobox-as-cell-editor-java-awt-illegalcomponentstateexception-component-must), you maybe have issues with your layouts: using JRE 1.7.0_u45 on Win7, I don't get any Exception with your code, but the current combobox item String is not correctly painted though.

Comment: Haven't you forget `.getContentPane()` when adding your panels/components at the end? Like `mainFrame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel());`

Answer (score 0):

```
Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?
```

No, because you do not give complete information.

Since the question is not worth making a runnable example to you, I did it: I added the vars mainFrame, choices, and choice, and gave string values to the choices array, I eliminated the "String" parameter from JComboBox type (running 1.6, JComboBox is not generic), and I commented out the call to handleSelection.  I start the UI, and can select values from the drop-down multiple times with no error.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class ComboBoxPlay
    {

      private static JFrame mainFrame = null;
      private static String[] choices = {"one", "two", "three" };
      private static String choice = null;

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         mainFrame = new JFrame();
        createMainMenu();

      }

      public static void createMainMenu(){
        mainFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();

        mainFrame.setSize(700 , 500);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3 , 3));

        JPanel ramStatus = new JPanel();
        ramStatus.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        ramStatus.setSize(200 , 200);

        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Please Select An Option to Continue.");

        JComboBox userChoice = new JComboBox();

        for(int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++)
            userChoice.addItem(choices[i]);

        userChoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)e.getSource();

            choice = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }});

        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    //        handleSelection(choice);
        }});

        mainFrame.add(new JPanel());
        mainFrame.add(userChoice);
        mainFrame.add(enter);

        mainFrame.add(new JPanel());
        mainFrame.add(heading);
        mainFrame.add(new JPanel());

        mainFrame.add(new JPanel());
        mainFrame.add(ramStatus);
        mainFrame.add(new JPanel());

        //Set the frame visible.
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```