# component must be showing on the screen to determine its location when changing JCOMBOX

Tags: java, swing, error-handling, jcombobox

I am receiving this error when i change items in the Jcombobox, nothing breaks it just shows this error, is there anyway to just throw it so it doesn't show up. everything still works fine, but if you wish to have a look at the code. i will post below.

Error message:

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2056)
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2030)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$23.call(CAccessibility.java:395)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$23.call(CAccessibility.java:393)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$CallableWrapper.run(LWCToolkit.java:538)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
```

And my code which i don't know which section to show so its all their.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class TouchOn extends JDialog {
private JPanel mainPanel;


public ArrayList Reader(String Txtfile) {
    try {

    ArrayList<String> Trains = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;
    String testing = "";
    File file = new File(Txtfile);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        count += count;
        if(!line.contains("*")){
            Trains.add(line + "\n");
        }
        stringBuffer.append("\n");



    }
    fileReader.close();
    //Arrays.asList(Trains).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
    return Trains;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//return toString();
return null;


}


public TouchOn()
{
    setPanels();

    setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void setPanels()
{
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JLabel startDay = new JLabel("Day:");
    JTextField sDay = new JTextField();

    JLabel startMonth = new JLabel("Month:");
    JTextField sMonth = new JTextField();

    JLabel startYear = new JLabel("Year:");
    JTextField sYear = new JTextField("2015");
    String trainline = "";

    JLabel touchOnTimehr = new JLabel("Time Hour: ");
    JLabel touchOnTimem = new JLabel("Time Minute:");
    JLabel station = new JLabel("Station: ");


    JTextField touchOnTimeFieldhour = new JTextField();
    JTextField touchOnTimeFieldminute = new JTextField();

    JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    ArrayList<String> stations = Reader("TrainLines.txt");
    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()]));
    JRadioButton belgrave = new JRadioButton("Belgrave Line");
    belgrave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            }
    });
    JRadioButton glenwaverly = new JRadioButton("Glen Waverly Line");
    glenwaverly.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        }
    });
    ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
    JButton apply = new JButton("Touch on");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
        }
    });
    apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {


String timestamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
            String day = sDay.getText();
            String month = sMonth.getText();
            String year = sYear.getText();
            String hour = touchOnTimeFieldhour.getText();
            String minute = touchOnTimeFieldminute.getText();
            if(belgrave.isSelected()){
                String trainline = belgrave.getText();
            }
            if(glenwaverly.isSelected()){
                String trainline = glenwaverly.getText();
            }
            System.out.println(trainline);
        }
    });



    cb.setVisible(true);
    bG.add(belgrave);
    bG.add(glenwaverly);
    mainPanel.add(startDay);
    mainPanel.add(sDay);
    mainPanel.add(startMonth);
    mainPanel.add(sMonth);
    mainPanel.add(startYear);
    mainPanel.add(sYear);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimehr);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldhour);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimem);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldminute);
    mainPanel.add(belgrave);
    mainPanel.add(glenwaverly);
    mainPanel.add(station);
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
    mainPanel.add(cb);
    lowerPanel.add(apply);
    lowerPanel.add(cancel);
    touchOnTimeFieldhour.setSize(10,10);
    containerPanel.add(mainPanel);
    containerPanel.add(lowerPanel);

    add(containerPanel);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't create multiple JComboBoxes and then swap visibility. Instead use one JComboBox and create multiple combo box models, such as by using `DefaultComboBoxModel<String>`, and then swap out the model that it holds by using its `setModel(...)` method. Problem solved.

---

Note that using a variation on your code -- I'm not able to reproduce your problem:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFoo2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndDisplayGui();
         }
      });
   }

   public static void createAndDisplayGui() {
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Press Me") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            TouchOn2 touchOn2 = new TouchOn2(frame);
            touchOn2.setVisible(true);
         }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(button);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TouchOn2 extends JDialog {
   private JPanel mainPanel;

   @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unused" })
   public ArrayList Reader(String Txtfile) {
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         list.add("Data String Number " + (i + 1));
      }

      // return toString();
      // !! return null;
      return list;
   }

   public TouchOn2(Window owner) {
      super(owner);
      setPanels();

      setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      setSize(400, 300);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public void setPanels() {
      mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
      JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      JLabel startDay = new JLabel("Day:");
      final JTextField sDay = new JTextField();

      JLabel startMonth = new JLabel("Month:");
      final JTextField sMonth = new JTextField();

      JLabel startYear = new JLabel("Year:");
      final JTextField sYear = new JTextField("2015");
      final String trainline = "";

      JLabel touchOnTimehr = new JLabel("Time Hour: ");
      JLabel touchOnTimem = new JLabel("Time Minute:");
      JLabel station = new JLabel("Station: ");

      final JTextField touchOnTimeFieldhour = new JTextField();
      final JTextField touchOnTimeFieldminute = new JTextField();

      JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      ArrayList<String> stations = Reader("TrainLines.txt");
      final JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(
            stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()]));
      final JRadioButton belgrave = new JRadioButton("Belgrave Line");
      belgrave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         }
      });
      final JRadioButton glenwaverly = new JRadioButton("Glen Waverly Line");
      glenwaverly.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         }
      });
      ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
      JButton apply = new JButton("Touch on");
      JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
      cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
         }
      });
      apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String timestamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
                  .format(new Date());
            String day = sDay.getText();
            String month = sMonth.getText();
            String year = sYear.getText();
            String hour = touchOnTimeFieldhour.getText();
            String minute = touchOnTimeFieldminute.getText();
            if (belgrave.isSelected()) {
               // !! ***** note you're shadowing variables here!!!! ****
               String trainline = belgrave.getText();
            }
            if (glenwaverly.isSelected()) {
               // !! and here too
               String trainline = glenwaverly.getText();
            }
            System.out.println(trainline);
         }
      });

      cb.setVisible(true);
      bG.add(belgrave);
      bG.add(glenwaverly);
      mainPanel.add(startDay);
      mainPanel.add(sDay);
      mainPanel.add(startMonth);
      mainPanel.add(sMonth);
      mainPanel.add(startYear);
      mainPanel.add(sYear);
      mainPanel.add(touchOnTimehr);
      mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldhour);
      mainPanel.add(touchOnTimem);
      mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldminute);
      mainPanel.add(belgrave);
      mainPanel.add(glenwaverly);
      mainPanel.add(station);
      mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
      mainPanel.add(cb);
      lowerPanel.add(apply);
      lowerPanel.add(cancel);
      touchOnTimeFieldhour.setSize(10, 10);
      containerPanel.add(mainPanel);
      containerPanel.add(lowerPanel);

      add(containerPanel);
   }

}
```

Comment: WOW, wait what, setModels()? I'm not to sure how to do this, I'm very new at this, and i was having the problem as you can tell with the commented out code, so i just thought this was easier

Comment: @VaughanD: If you're new then this is a perfect time for you to check out the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html), and in particular its entry on the [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html). It will tell you what constructors and methods are available for this class.

Comment: okay I've made it all one combobox and I'm still getting the error, message when selecting different list items

Comment: @VaughanD: It's hard to way what's wrong without seeing the latest code and error message. Please [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30286687/edit) (click on the link I've provided) and add your latest code at the end of your question.

Comment: @VaughanD: which line throws the exception?

Comment: it doesn't say which line. but its when i change the combo box value, would it be because there isn't a action on changing it ?

Comment: @VaughanD: I'm trying to run your code, and at present am not able to. What does the data file look like?

Comment: i have my main GUI running to this screen, so I'm not to sure how to run it by itself.. and what do you mean by data file? sorry

Comment: @VaughanD: why does your `reader(...)` method return `null`?? By data file, the data that is read in by reader and then used in the JComboBox.

Comment: oh sorry, and i couldn't get around it not returning null.. i had the first return  and eclipse gives it an error, and the data file is just 
*** Belgrave line *** 
Parliament Station 
Melbourne Central Station 
Flagstaff Station
Southern Cross Station 
Flinders Street Station 
Richmond Station
East Richmond Station 
Burnley Station 
Hawthorn Station 
Glenferrie Station 
Auburn Station 
            Sorry i cannot format replies. but there just individual lines

Comment: @VaughanD: I tried to run your code after modifying it not to need a file, but I cannot reproduce your problem. See code above.

Comment: yea i can see how it would be difficult, i tried to implement the       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 because i  read that it helps, but its still giving me the errors...

BTW
when you say shadowing variables what do you mean ? I'm trying to save the string that the user selects. with the button group..

Comment: @VaughanD: the trainLine Strings that are declared within the if and else blocks are only visible within those blocks. The String variable with the same name declared within your setPanels method is a completely distinct and separate variable. Changing the state of the variables within the if block will not effect the variable declared within the method. I think that perhaps you will want to declare a single trainLine variable and declare it as an instance variable within the class.

Comment: @VaughanD: note a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968815/jcombobox-as-cell-editor-java-awt-illegalcomponentstateexception-component-must).

Comment: Okay, from process off eliminations its my reader function bringing in the text file into arrays, with each new line. but I'm not to sure how to do the reading text file any other way..

Comment: @VaughanD: Is it supposed to read in one file of stations for each JRadioButton? What are the names of the files? Do the files have the radiobutton names inside of them as well? I would read the data directly into `DefaultComboBoxModel<String>` objects, and associate each model object with a String (the line name) by using a `HashMap<String, ComboBoxModel>`. This would allow easy swapping of models.

Comment: I've have decided to just have 2 radio buttons, and one drop down with all the stations in it. so one main text file holding all the train stations. and just two radio buttons. so no need to swap models. because it was becoming difficult for me to understand.